# HD 5870 displayport low power no image on Dell UltraSharp U2414H 23.8

Tags: windows-7, amd-radeon, displayport

NOTE: I bought a cable for HDMI and now the resolution is at 1920x1020 I would prefer to at least understand how to fix the display port

I have a windows 7 desktop with and AMD HD 5870 graphics card. I have recently bought a Dell UltraSharp U2414H 23.8. I connected it to my HD 5870 display port and everything seemed to be fine.

A few weeks later the monitor stopped displaying image. It is detected by windows (I am using a second monitor and can see it on the screen resolution dialog) but it just doesn't show any image when connected using display port.

If I switch to HDMI I can see the image but not at a great resolution (I have everything connected and windows shows 3 monitors but 2 are the Dell connected via display port and HDMI).

The HDMI resolution is only of 800x600 (it doesn't allow me to change)

NOTE: I can see the BIOS and the start up messages if I have another monitor connected. It seems that if I have the second monitor the Dell monitor gets enough power at least for the start up but when it reaches the login window it goes dark.

I have googled a lot this and found some forums saying there might be a problem with windows and sleep mode, if it enters sleep mode it might disable something in the graphics card and prevent it from displaying the image.

I can't find a proper solution for this. Does anyone know how I can reactivate what might have been deactivated by windows in sleep mode or just how to fix this properly?

PS: I am getting a few warning dialogs when I switch to display port (clicking on the help button shows me a web page with some text that doesn't really explain much)

http://imagebin.org/323023
http://imagebin.org/323024

Comment: 800x600 is an interesting resolution.  It is the one used by windows 7 when there is no vendor graphics driver installed. 

Questions:
Did you update the drivers after it previously worked?
Can you check the status in `devmgmt.msc` ? (e.g no yellow exclamation mark).

Comment: @Hennes It shows up fine. I have connected with HDMI and I can use the monitor the problem now is at 1920x1020 but it doesn't show the image properly (it doesn't fill the screen)